# Mint Token in token2022 has name, symbol info, how can it? Does token2022 support metadata?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, token, metadata

From my knowledge, Token2022's Mint account is don't have name and symbol info:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/6edf3ecc3f51a9f7a6faba9a1a4d30f1e4857e69/token/program-2022/src/state.rs#L22

And, I create a demo: https://beta.solpg.io/65d4bda7cffcf4b13384cf6b

then I got an Mint Token:
https://solscan.io/token/EyWttuRYY5NdvdmiRmzENLZiUaVtsoGfhvonaBfWE8fZ?cluster=devnet
who's owner is TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA which is Token2020 program. And it does have name, symbol info. Isn't it violate the Mint struct in Token2020 program?

and, second question: what's the relationship of spl-token-metadata-interface and metaplex token-metadata program?

Answer (score 0):

After dig into SPL token-program source code and metaplex's MPL program code, it prove that 'create_metadata_accounts_v3' from anchor-spl actually a wrapper  of MPL's create_metadata_accounts_v3, and the token this API create IS SPL token2020. The metadata do not store in token's Mint Account, but stored in MPL program PDA accounts.

As to question 2), spl-token-metadata-interface is just a helper API to interact with metaplex token-metadata.